# VSCode task in WSL environment, terminal keeps exiting when trying to run shell script

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-tasks

**NOTE**
I've had to remove like two chunks of this post because stack overflow kept interpreting it as code when it isn't and it wouldn't let me post, I'll just make a screenshot of what the post is supposed to look like and post it [here](https://gist.github.com/MoHKale/0999461295989a349e7b5b2cd2608a69). Read this instead.

## Summary

I was finally trying to learn how to use VSCode tasks and so I copied the first task example from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) and created a shell script at scripts/test.sh which contains simply "echo foo". I also commented out the windows alternative script because I exclusively use WSL/Bash. Whenever I run the task I receive a "The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1" error message, which is no help whatsoever.

## Testing

I ran various tests and I have no idea why this isn't working.

### Proving The Task Is In The Correct Directory & In WSL

First I thought maybe the task isn't running in WSL or that the directories are out of sync, so I changed the commands to see what happens.

First, I changed it to:

```
"command": "pwd",
```

and the output was "/mnt/f/.../.../tmp/tmp.1BitOIA78E" (... are for some arbitrary path) so clearly I concluded I was running on WSL and in the right path.

### Proving the Script is Executeable

Next I thought, maybe the script I'm trying to run isn't executable or something to that affect, so I changed the command to:

```
"command": "stat ./scripts/test.sh",
```

and I got the following output which shows, the file exists, it's executeable & can be accessed through "./scripts/test.sh" from whatever directory the Task is set to on construction

I run the task by typing ctrl-shift-P to open the menu, select "run tasks" and then select 'My First Task'.

Note: I don't think this is a settings problem. There're no workspace settings setup (because this is just me testing) & just in case, you can find my current user settings [here](https://gist.github.com/MoHKale/8fd1b7b598110929b189171c5b07a2e0) which I updated immediately before posting this.

## Expectations

What I'd like is either:

- Someone to tell me how I can access the stderr and stdout log of the shell upon startup so I can get some actually helpful information as to why this is happening.
- Someone to tell me why I can run a script perfectly fine outside of a task, but within a task it completely fails.

Whats also of note is that the script isn't the problem here. Leaving it completely blank, doesn't stop the terminal from straight up crashing.

Comment: I am also getting exactly this problem on WSL2. Same successful results of `stat` and `pwd`.